# Compiling gives different results than windows compiler

Tags: c, linux, windows, compilation

I tried to compile and run some old C programs that I developed years back on windows with codeblocks.

I get no error from gcc and program executes correctly. Only in some cases (some initial conditions), I do not get the same numerical results as before! I did not change anything in my program (except sed the `^M` characters).

I first thought it was because of the two scanf functions. But no. I removed them and get the same erroneous results.

Did anyone encounter that kind of strange behavior before when using a Windows C code to linux?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "differentialeqsolve.h"

#define TINY 1.0e-30

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*main*/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(void){

/*miscellaneous variables*/
int i,k,dummy;
int N=4;                          /*nb equa diff +1 (we don't want to use f[0])*/

/*output files*/
char namefile[20]={0};        /*file for couplings*/
FILE * file[N];

/*Runge Kutta variables*/
double accuracy=1e-7;             /*minimal precision required for values of f obtained by rk*/
double h=1.0e-7;                  /*initial step for RG (for the first iteration)*/
double htry,hdid,hnext;           /*initial/effective/final step for rk5adapt*/
double t=0.;                      /*RG time*/
double limite=1.0e12;              /*cutoff limit for the strong coupling*/

double U,J;                    /*lattice parameters for initial conditions*/
int NN;                           /*number of spin components*/

double thetamin,thetamax,dtheta;
double theta;
double R=0.1;

int n=100;                        /*number of points in the calculation around the ring*/

double f[N];
double df[N];
double fscal[N];
double g[N];                      /*renormalized (by f1) couplings*/

/*opening output files*/
for (k = 1 ; k < N ; k++ )
        {sprintf(namefile,"g%d.dat",k);
        file[k]=fopen(namefile, "w");}

/*initialization of couplings f[]*/

NN=3;

thetamin = -0.1;
thetamax = 0.1;

dtheta=(thetamax-thetamin)/((float) n);
printf("dtheta=%.10lf\n",dtheta);

for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
   theta=thetamin+i*dtheta;
   U=R*cos(theta);
   J=R*sin(theta);

   /*initialization of table df[]*/
    for(k=1;k<N;k++) df[k]=0;

    f[1]=-2*NN*U-3*NN*J;
    f[2]=-2*NN*U+NN*J+2*NN*NN*J;
    f[3]=-2*NN*U+NN*J;

    t=0.;              /*initialization of RG time*/

    /*initialization of RG time step for rk5adapt*/
    htry=h;
    /*calculation of the scaling to calculate precision*/
    for(k=1;k<N;k++)
        fscal[k]=fabs(f[k])+fabs(df[k]*htry)+TINY;

    /* ********************************************************/
    /*iteration of RG until at least one of the couplings reaches the cutoff "limite"*/
    /* ********************************************************/
    for(;;){
    /*calculation of f(t+h) with rk5adapt*/
        rk5adapt(f,df,N,NN,&t,htry,accuracy,fscal,&hdid,&hnext,dfunctions);
        /*new time is readily set by rk5adapt*/
        /*new step (set as hnext by rk5adapt)*/
        htry=hnext;
        /*new scaling fscal*/
        for(k=1;k<N;k++)
            fscal[k]=fabs(f[k])+fabs(df[k]*htry)+TINY;

    /*Stop RG iteration when at least one of the couplings reaches the cutoff limit*/
        for(k=1;k<N;k++)
            {if(fabs(f[k])>=limite) {goto RGstop;}}

    }
    RGstop : if(f[1]>0) for(k=1;k<N;k++)
             {
                g[k]=f[k]/f[1];
                fprintf(file[k],"%lf %lf\n",theta,g[k]);
             }
             else printf("%lf, g[1]<0\n",theta);

/*end theta*/
}

for ( k = 1 ; k < N ; k++ )
{
    fclose(file[k]);
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Post the code that gives different results

Comment: Ok, I just posted the code. I hesitated because it's long. It's using the function rk5adapt that is the runge kutta code only slightly modified from Numerical Recipes. I have used it so much that I don't think the problem comes from there.

Comment: I think you're going to have to output variables at various points until you find the specific discrepancies. Also, try compiling with GCC under Windows to see if this is a platform issue or a compiler issue.

Comment: If the behavior changes between compilers you probably have ... undefined behavior.

Comment: I'd suggest that a change in bit depth of your OS may be the source of the numeric change -- 32-bit systems may store some numeric values differently from 64-bit systems (rounding will take place at different values in a 64-bit vs. a 128-bit number).  The OS you were using "years ago" was likely 32-bit; if you're on 64-bit Linux, now...

Comment: @bosonfute How different are the results? Are you running with the same processor as well as different OS's? Different FPU's could handle floating point arithmetic *slightly* differently. This wouldn't result in drastic changes (epsilon differences most likely) but those can add up to be noticeably different. (This would only be the case if you're getting like 2.00000002 when the old data is 2.0).

Comment: @IdeaHat My hardware is totally different and my OS as well. I've got drastically different results. 
I narrowed down my problem. For instance, for N=3, I've got updates of my f functions (df != 0), even if I think it still leads to wrong results. And for N=4, I get no update (df = 0). I used the same function in python (the function defining the updates), and it's giving me df != 0). So my df function is not ill-defined.

I'm now going to check if it is due to my parameters used in the Runge Kutta algorithm (I've got tiny parameters like 1e-30).

Comment: What is the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`?  Reporting the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` will add insight as to the precision/range code is using.

Comment: Minor: cast is unnecessary and restrictive: `dtheta=(thetamax-thetamin)/((float) n);`.  Should be `dtheta = (thetamax-thetamin)/n;` or `dtheta = (thetamax-thetamin)/((double) n);`  Of course if `n` remains with small values like 100, this is not a significant issue.

Comment: The code uses arrays index from `1` to `N-1` rather than the usual `0` to `N-1` and never initializes values like `f[0]`.  So wondering if in the posted/unposted code, `f[0], g[0]` , etc somehow might get used or if `g` , etc. is initialized.    Suggest completely initializing all variables.

Comment: Zeiss Ikon put me on tracks. I just changed the `TINY` parameter from `1e-30̀ (as chosen in the code of Numerical Recipes) to `1e-25̀. It worked! Only, I don't really understand why!

Comment: @chux I've got FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0. I'm not sure what to make of it. Thanks for your remark about casting. I wasn't doing it in the beginning but I remember my advisor asking me to. As for the array being used from 1 to N-1, I know it's weird. It never posed problems in the past. But I'll keep in mind. Actually I should rewrite this code to avoid this.

Comment: `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` indicates if floating point math maybe evaluating at higher formats.  KNowing `FLT_ROUNDS` is the next step.  One of the challenges with this question is lack of specificity. "different results" is not that helpful.  Instead saying inputs were "1.0, 2.0, 3.14159 and output was 123.412345 yet 123.567890 was expected" and details about `rk5adapt()` would be useful.  Without more insight, this is too general a problem.  Note: C does not specify precision nor the accuracy of FP math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem by setting the `TINY` parameter (see Runge Kutta in Numerical Recipes) to `1e-25`. Before it was set at `1e-30`.

Apparently, my compiler does not treat float and float operations the same way my old compiler did.

Following chux remarks, I checked the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` which was `0`. Setting it to `2` changed a little bit the results of my differential equations but it's only when I set `TINY` to a different value that I finally got the expected results.